# NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm trying to connect mysql and change info but isn't work.

main.py

```
import pymysql

def connect_setting():
    # Trying to connect
    db_connection = None
    try:
        db_connection = pymysql.connect(
        user='db', 
        passwd='password', 
        host='127.0.0.1', 
        db='test', 
        charset='utf8'
        )
       # If connection is not successful
    except:
        print("Can't connect to database")
        return 0
    # If Connection Is Successful
        print("Connected")

    # Making Cursor Object For Query Execution
        global cursor
        cursor = db_connection.cursor()


def get_off():

    sql = '''INSERT INTO `-100`'''

    cursor.execute(sql)
    db_connection.commit()
```

index.py

```
from main import get_off as sql

sql()
```

error

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/Kakao_points/index.py", line 3, in <module>
    sql()
  File "/workspace/Kakao_points/main.py", line 30, in get_off
    cursor.execute(sql)
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

I already defined cursor but somehow python didn't get info in next def I guess.. anybody please help..?

Comment: You only assign `cursor` when there's an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only setting `cursor` when the connection fails, because you put those lines in the `except:` block. Those two lines should be in the `try:` block.

You also need to make `db_connection` global so you can use it in the other function.

```
def connect_setting():
    global db_connection
    # Trying to connect
    db_connection = None
    try:
        db_connection = pymysql.connect(
        user='db', 
        passwd='password', 
        host='127.0.0.1', 
        db='test', 
        charset='utf8'
        )

        # Making Cursor Object For Query Execution
        global cursor
        cursor = db_connection.cursor()
        # If Connection Is Successful
        print("Connected")
    # If connection is not successful
    except:
        print("Can't connect to database")
        return 0
```

Comment: I literally changed same as yours but still same error
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

Comment: Are you getting the `Connected` message?

Comment: yes also I thought I didn't turn on mysql service but it was on and python prints "connected" as well.

Comment: I can't think of a reason. I updated the answer to say that you also need `global db_connection`, but that doesn't affect `cursor`.

Comment: Hmm,I still working in another way but same output :C

Comment: I changed main.py to index.py and execute it it's working I guess import error maybe